# Missionary gave me these Talmudic quotes; Does it prove that Goyim are viewed as Animals who should be harassed, and that christians will go to hell?

Tags: gentiles, talmud-gemara, christianity

Sorry about this. I'm not a Talmudic scholar in any sense; Can anyone qualify if what presented here is accurate and as bad as it sounds?

> “The ‘goyim’ are not humans. They are beasts.”

(Baba Mezia 114b)

> “If you eat with a ‘goy’ it is the same as eating with a dog.”

(Tosapoth, Jebamoth 94b)

> “Even the best of the ‘goyim’ should all be killed.”

(Soferim 15)

> “Sexual intercourse between the ‘goyim’ is like intercourse between animals.”

(Sanhedrin 74b)

> “When it comes to a Gentile in peace times, one may harm him indirectly, for instance, by removing a ladder after he had fallen into a crevice.”

(Shulkan Arukh, Yoreh De ‘ah, 158, Hebrew Edition only)

> “If a ‘goy’ (Gentile) hits a Jew he must be killed.”

(Sanhedrin 58b)

> “If a Jew finds an object lost by a ‘goy’ it does not have to be returned.”

(Baba Mezia 24a)

> “If a Jew murders a ‘goy’ there will be no death penalty.” (Sanhedrin 57a) What a Jew steals from a ‘goy’ he may keep.”

(Sanhedrin 57a)

> “Jews may use subterfuges to circumvent a ‘goy.’” (Baba Kamma 113a) “All children of the ‘goyim’ (Gentiles) are animals.”

(Yebamoth 98a)

> “Girls born of the ‘goyim’ are in a state of ‘niddah’ (menstrual uncleanness!) from birth.”

(Abodah Zarah 36b)

> “‘Yashu’ (derogatory for ‘Jesus’) is in Hell being boiled in hot excrement.”

(Gittin 57a) [’Yashu’ is an acronym for the Jewish curse, ‘May his (Jesus) name be wiped out forevermore.’]

> Yashu (Jesus) was sexually immoral and worshipped a brick.”

(Sanhedrin 107b)

> “Yashu (Jesus) was cut off from the Jewish people for his wickedness and
>   refused to repent.”

(Sotah 47a)

> “Miriam the hairdresser had sex with many men.”

(Shabbath 104b, Hebrew Edition only)

> “She who was the descendant of princes and governors (the virgin Mary) played the harlot with carpenters.”

(Sanhedrin 106a)*

> “Christians who reject the Talmud will go to hell and be punished there for all generations.”

(Rosh Hashanah 17a)

Comment: What do you mean by "Hebrew edition only"?

Comment: I have no idea what he meant.

Comment: At least the quote about returning lost objects is a legal point, not a moral point per se. I have heard it explained that there are certain law that are in place because we must treat everyone as humans. There are certain ones, such as returning  lost objects, that are not morally required because of treating people as humans but because we have a higher level obligation to our family. Jews are our family but Christians aren't. So it isn't that we exclude Christians from returning lost objects, rather there is just not reason to add them in the first place.

Comment: Think about it, we treat our family different than we treat random people on the street.

Comment: The oldest trick in the missionary book is to quote out of context. Let's take your first quote which in the original says אתם קרויין אדם ואין עובדי כוכבים קרויין אדם  - _you (the Jews) are called Adam (human? person?) and the idol worshippers are not called Adam_ and not _“The ‘goyim’ are not humans. They are beasts.”_ - The context is a Pasuk (Yechezkel 34:31 - וְאַתֵּן צֹאנִי צֹאן מַרְעִיתִי אָדָם אַתֶּם - You are my sheep whom I graze, you are Adam) to prove that the graves of non-Jews do not cause Tumah-impurity the way Jewish graves do.

Comment: I'm familiar with many of the quotes, and most of them are clearly out-of-context. Since you mention that you're a _Talmudic scholar_ (it says so clearly in your question) you should be able to handle this. (Now don't go telling me that you're not; why would context matter? You've clearly written _Talmudic scholar_ in your introduction.)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56393/are-these-teachings-of-the-jewish-talmud-and-does-a-typical-jew-believe-this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31053/is-this-really-in-the-talmud

Comment: I wish I knew what "Hebrew Edition only" meant, and why would it matter that some woman named Miriam slept with some guys? As to the final quote, it is a misquote. The text says "Heretics, Mosrim and Apikorsim, " which are categories of apostate Jews, not Christians. All it says about non-Jews is that, just like Jews, "Jews and non-Jews who have sinned with their bodies descend to Gehinom for 12 months".

Comment: as for the supposed Jesus references http://www.angelfire.com/mt/talmud/jesus.html and http://www.angelfire.com/mt/talmud/jesusnarr.html and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47327/what-does-the-talmud-rabbinic-writing-have-to-say-about-yeishu-hanotzri-jesus

Comment: @DannySchoemann His introduction said **I'm not a Talmudic scholar in any sense** so he would need to have the basics explained. Perhaps [Jews for Judaism](http://www.jewsforjudaism.org) could help as well. It would also depend on where he lives for a local organization that could help.

Comment: @andrewmh20 Perhaps the missionary was pretending that the Art Scroll edition (as an example of an English translation) should not be read since it would show the falseness of the claims.

Comment: One possible issue with this question that I think is keeping it from getting an answer is that it's hard to address all the cases above together, as they each have an individual explanation.

Comment: I should also point out that the term Yshu (yud shin vav) may also be a generic term for any heretic (from the initial letters of a phrase) rather than the name "jesus".

Comment: @andrewitmh20 Perhaps it would need to be closed as too broad then.

Comment: @sabbahillel I certainly understand this, and was considering asking these questions individually. I did not want to be accused of spamming this stack exchange though. This is why I said "sorry" ~

Comment: I've read the same evidence  on stormfront and other white racialist (not racist) web sites as well as by eminent authors such as David Duke so it MUST be true! The problem is this. David Duke so happens to be a man of great insight and many things he discusses are correct. However, that does not mean that he does not make errors in fact---accidental, naively or intentionally. It so happens much of what the OP quoted is what is written. However, what is overlooked is looking at the entire text. The Talmud is not a book of proverbs, quick snippets of rabbinical law. It's absurd to people.......

Comment: ....who are in the know to believe those who quote such things actually read the entire Talmud which, for those who don't know, is not a two-volume set of books.  Other that said, there are Jews who may misinterpret the Talmud but that is an error of true scholarship and mythology. The fact many Jews misinterpret scripture and rabbinical teachings, is it surprising that less knowledgeable do the same? I do not intend to address each quote but I will say that seriously knowledgable Jewish scholars, including Maimonides, have made quite positive comments about Jesus, Chrisitianity and Islam.

Comment: One last thought. The term "Goy" literally means "nation". Israel is referred to as "goys" in one or two places in scripture Psalms?). Of course "goy" can also be used in a derogatory way as well. The Talmud's discussions  concerning non-Jews typically  refers to heathens NOT peoples who are monothesiatic. So while the Talmud is quite hostile towards paganism, it is not so towards Chrisitanity. Islam? Islam did not even exist at the time the Talmud was compiled. By the way, Chrisitanity also harbors similar hostility to paganism. Let's discuss what the church says about relationships between

Comment: @JJLL [The Talmud](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26265/759), and normative Judaism, does not view Christianity as monotheistic, but as Avoda Zara.

Comment: Maimonides said that Christians and Muslims believe in the same God as do  Jews. Any follower of rhe Noahide Laws is by definition monothesiatic . I understand your  point. Catholics who believe in the trinity raises questions, including that of the Protesant church. To the best of my knowledge, the Catholic Church understands the father, son and Holy Spirit as different aspects of the one true God. Not exactly the same but not too dissimilar to Judaisms concept of different aspects of God indicated bt the numerous names given depicting mercy, love, judgment, jealousy, grace, vengeance, etc.

Comment: Hey @DoubleAA.  I realize that my comment on Maimonides may have been incorrect. I know that there was a Mi Yodeya thread on the topic "Is Christianity Avodah Zara" but I'll check my source as well. I am reasonably certain though that Protesants rejection of the Holy Trinity is different.

Comment: @JJLL The vast majority of protestants do not reject the trinity, and Maimonides thought Christianity was straight up Avoda Zara.

Comment: Yes, @DoubleAA. Protesants for the most part reject the Trinity.

Comment: @JJLL No, they almost all believe in the Trinity. Pretty much the only ones you've probably heard of who do reject the Trinity are the JWitnesses and the Mormans.

Comment: @Doub You're probably right about belief in the Trinity but I'm not convinced that the Trinity is perceived in any other way than three aspects of one God. As stated above Double, I'm thinking that the Trinity is similar to multiple attributes. Judaism attributes to God. Looking at it objectively, it would appear that Judaism believes in multiple Gods (El, YHVH, Shaddai, etc.) with human-like attributes (mercy, kindness, vengeance, anger, etc.) We know God's various names are only descriptors of God's unity that can we can only scratch the surface of understanding through use of familiar terms

Comment: @JJLL See this question http://mi.yodeya.com/a/59680 and whatever you or Christians think of the Trinity, the traditional Jewish position about it has been to consider it polytheistic Avoda Zara.

Comment: Why don't you [just verify it yourself](http://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud) ? Since [the Babylonian one](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/talmud.htm) is already translated, you can use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) to inspect the one from Jerusalem.