# Does the Gemara teach that Jews are allowed to kill gentiles but not vice versa?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, gentiles, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, hukot-hagoyim

> The Gemara challenges: But wherever there is liability for capital punishment, this tanna teaches it; as it is taught in the first clause: ***With regard to bloodshed, if a gentile murders another gentile, or a gentile murders a Jew, he is liable.*** ***If a Jew murders a gentile, he is exempt***. Evidently, the term liable is used in the baraita. ([Sanhedrin 57a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.57a.16?lang=bi&with=Halakhah&lang2=en))

What is the meaning of these words?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/134283/27180

Comment: Exempt doesn't equal allowed, and I think you know that

Comment: The very next line says that it's not permitted. Also, I *think* it's talking about idol worshippers.

Comment: The [Kessef Mishneh says](https://www.sefaria.org/Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Murderer_and_the_Preservation_of_Life.2.11.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi) that it means their fath is not in hands of a human court, but in hands of Heavenly court

Comment: @Shmuel It seems to me the logic is like this: 1) gentile kills gentile or Jew kills Jew, the killer is liable because they are both of equal status. 2) Gentile kills Jew, gentile is killed because he killed someone of higher status. 3) Jew kills gentile, he killed someone of lower status and therefore we can't take his life because they are not equal (at face value, and it is up to Hashem to decide the punishment).